# Shortcut key for closing find function (ctrl + f) in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-7

Is there a shortcut key to close or reset the find function (ctrl + f) in Netbeans?

PS. ESCAPE does work, but i want to be able to close it even if my cursor is not active in the search field.

Comment: Escape would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press escape to close the find-window.

Comment: Yes, but i need to have the cursor inside the search field so its active. I would like to close it when i am outside the box.

Comment: Hm... what about CTRL+F, ESC? Another way is not known to me.

Comment: I guess, its a solution :-)